# PHP determining distances

Tags: php

I have a huge array of 30x100 representing a football field. I make players move in it. However, when the ball is throwed, I need to determine if other players are within a +/-1 reach of the trajectory to possibly intercept the pass.

Since some (and most) passes are thrown diagonally, I have a hard time figuring out how to determine an algorythm to evaluate such thing.

My field looks like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

Characters can only move from integrers (so each has a set of coordinates at every moment, such as (3,2) or (20,90).

What would be the simplest way of finding out if a player is within a certain range of my pass trajectory (say the pass goes from (2,4) to (30,15))?

Comment: Same question except not specific to PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment. The answers there cover the slightly easier case where what you want is the distance to the *line*, and the more complicated one -- which I think is what you want here -- of the distance to the *line segment*. If the difference isn't clear: is the distance between (-1000,1) and the line from (0,0) to (1,0) 1, or is it about 1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a passer at `($x0, $y0)`, a place where the pass will come down if nobody catches it `($x1, $y1)`, and a potential receiver at `($x, $y)`.  You want to find out the distance between the receiver at `($x, $y)` and the line from `($x0, $y0)` to `($x1, $y1)`.

That's given by this equation:

```
$d = abs( ( $x1 - $x0 ) *  ( $y0 - $y ) - ( $x0 - $x ) * ($y1 - $y0 ) ) / 
    sqrt( pow( $x1 - $x0, 2 ) + pow ($y1 - $y0, 2 ) );
```

You can find a derivation [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html).

That only gets you the distance to the (infinitely long) *line*, however, which may be outside the line *segment* containing the pass.  To get the right answer, see Grumdrig's answer here: [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

Comment: Although true for two points, this is slightly less useful for a point and a line.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think we are almost at it with your equation. As you said, this gives us the distance to the infinite line. However, with a simple if/else statement, I could make sure that the "3rd player" is within the min-1 and the max+1 "y" coordinate of the passer and the receiver, or else he cannot intercept.

Comment: I think you want Grumdrig's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment

Comment: @MarkReed I do not understand why he's using a float there. Also, what is the dot function of C++? I prefer your 100% PHP solution, even though I need to add an if/else condition to check whether I'm off the segment.

Comment: http://coding.pressbin.com/65/PHP-Find-shortest-distance-from-point-to-line-segment

This is exactly what I need here!

Answer (score 2):

Translate the passer to the origin, rotate the trajectory of the ball to the X axis, then check if any of the players near the path (i.e. same x coordinate sign) have a y coordinate between -1 and 1.

Comment: Seems a good idea. However, how would I rotate the trajectory of the ball to the X axis? I'd need a function to rotate everything, which sounds quite complex.

Comment: `atan2()` would give you the angle you need to rotate. You then multiply the translation matrix and the rotation matrix, and apply the resultant matrix to the points.

Answer (score 0):

[Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) is the way to go.

Comment: Except that "+/-1" is a narrower angle as the radius increases.

Comment: Yeah, though probably the easiest way is to find all the neighbor squares of the squares intersected by the hypotenuse. It's hard to be accurate on such a grid system.